# How to map parent's bean class variable in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Bean class called Bean_A that is map to table_A, and this Bean_A class is inherited from a base bean class, and the base bean class will have a unique_reference_key variable that will going to save into the database together with the Bean_A class. I already have the hibernate file ready for the Bean_A and the unique_reference_key field in table_A.

May I know how could I map the base bean class in hibernate to ensure this unique_reference_key variable is save into database when I was saving the Bean_A object? Take note that this base bean class is not map to any table in database, and there is no such table that "represent" the base bean.

Before I throw out this question, I have consult the following article but still couldn't get any clue on it.

1. [Hibernate simplifies inheritance mapping](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hibernate/)
2. [Hibernate Chapter 5.Basic O/R Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution on how to map the base bean property into Bean_A in hibernate.

In hibernate:

```
<class name="com.dao.pojo.BaseBean" abstract="true">
   <id name="theId" type="string">
      <column name="primary_key" length="15" />
   </id>
   <property name="unique_ref_key" type="java.lang.String" column="unique_ref_key"/>

   <union-subclass name="com.dao.pojo.Bean_A" table="table_A" lazy="false">
      ...
   </union-subclass>
</class>
```

Please note that **theId** was originally from Bean_A and it has been move to BaseBean. A new field, unique_ref_key, is created inside table_A.

In JAVA:

```
public abstract class BaseBean {
   private String theId;
   private String unique_ref_key;

   // getter and setter
}

public class Bean_A extends BeseBean {
   ...
}
```

Hope this solution can help others.

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptiin would be much clearer if you added some code. But I think you're just looking for the MappedSuperclass annotation, described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7287):

> 5.1.6.4. Inherit properties from superclasses
>
> This is sometimes useful to share common properties through a
>   technical or a business superclass without including it as a regular
>   mapped entity (ie no specific table for this entity). For that purpose
>   you can map them as @MappedSuperclass.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getLastUpdate() { ... }
    public String getLastUpdater() { ... }
    ...
}

@Entity class Order extends BaseEntity {
    @Id public Integer getId() { ... }
    ...
}
```